# Issue in calling Json response for the Webscript in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

- I have created **Json response file** in Company Home > Data Dictionary >
  Web Scripts > org >   alfresco > sample with the Name:
  folder.get.json.ftl for one of the Alfresco Web
  Script(http:// localhost:8080/alfresco/service/sample/folder/Company%20Home)according
  to the     guidelines mentioned in
  http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Ftasks%2Fws-json-add.html.
- After successful addition of the webscript , i have refresh the
  Webscripts.
- Now when im tring to call this websrcipt using the URL
  http:// localhost:8080/alfresco/service/sample/folder/Company%20Home?format=json
  i am getting Internal Error(500).

Please help me out regarding this.
Thanks in Advance!!!!

### Below is the stack trace

```
{
    "status" : 
  {
    "code" : 500,
    "name" : "Internal Error",
    "description" : "An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request."
  },  

  "message" : "01270141 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 01270216 Error during processing of the template 'Expression verbose is undefined on line 12, column 14 in org\/alfresco\/sample\/folder.get.json.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator.",  
  "exception" : "org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 01270141 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 01270216 Error during processing of the template 'Expression verbose is undefined on line 12, column 14 in org\/alfresco\/sample\/folder.get.json.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator.",

  "callstack" : 
  [ 
      ""      ,"freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression verbose is undefined on line 12, column 14 in org\/alfresco\/sample\/folder.get.json.ftl."
      ,"freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)"
      ,"freemarker.core.Expression.isTrue(Expression.java:145)"
      ,"freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:77)"
      ,"freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)"
      ,"freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)"
      ,"freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)"
      ,"freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:179)"
      ,"freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:428)"
      ,"freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102)"
      ,"freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)"
      ,"freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)"
      ,"freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)"
      ,"freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)"
      ,"org.alfresco.repo.template.FreeMarkerProcessor.process(FreeMarkerProcessor.java:202)"
      ,"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.renderTemplate(AbstractWebScript.java:714)"
      ,"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.renderFormatTemplate(DeclarativeWebScript.java:267)"
      ,"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:147)"
      ,"org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$2.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:400)"
      ,"org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388)"
      ,"org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:453)"
      ,"org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:491)"
      ,"org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:316)"
      ,"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:352)"
      ,"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:189)"
      ,"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118)"
      ,"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)"
      ,"org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)"
      ,"org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)"
      ,"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)"
      ,"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)"
      ,"org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)"
      ,"java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)"
      ,"org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TemplateException: 01270216 Error during processing of the template 'Expression verbose is undefined on line 12, column 14 in org\/alfresco\/sample\/folder.get.json.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator."
      ,"org.alfresco.repo.template.FreeMarkerProcessor.process(FreeMarkerProcessor.java:206)"
      ,"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 01270141 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 01270216 Error during processing of the template 'Expression verbose is undefined on line 12, column 14 in org\/alfresco\/sample\/folder.get.json.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator."
      ,"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:884)"

  ],

  "server" : "Community v4.0.0 (a r30055) schema 5,016",
  "time" : "Feb 27, 2012 9:53:23 AM"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key line is:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression verbose is undefined on line 12, column 14 in org/alfresco/sample/folder.get.json.ftl.
```

Your template, on line 12, character 14, you've referenced a variable "verbose" which doesn't exist. You should either set that variable in the model, or check if it's defined or not before using it.

Comment: Thanks...This being default webscript provided by alfresco...I have not hard coded anything...just added the code as they specified in http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Ftasks%2Fws-json-add.html....Can u please tell what i need to change in this particular code mentioned in Alfresco Guide...

Comment: You seem to have jumped into the last part of the tutorial, without doing the earlier bits! You need to start [at the beginning](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/ws-folderListing-intro.html) and work your way though. If you do that, you'll have a JS webscript generating the required model that your FTL requires

Comment: Thanks again...As i know i have followed all the steps starting from the creating description Documents...Guess i missed something...Let me recheck ...thanks :) Good day!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It worked now...But i need <a href tag > defined for each folder in the list..or can you please give me some guidelines to modify or add new json response file for the existing default alfresco Web Script (http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/sample/folder/Company%20Home)